# Can't edit parameters in an ABAP Selection-Screen?

Tags: parameters, abap

This is the code:

```
REPORT zwof_test_parameters.

PARAMETERS:
  p_a  TYPE c LENGTH 10 OBLIGATORY,
  p_b  TYPE c LENGTH 10,
  p_c  TYPE c LENGTH 10.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON p_a.
  p_b = p_a.
  p_c = p_a.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON p_b.
  p_c = p_b.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  WRITE:/ p_a, p_b, p_c.

END-OF-SELECTION.
```

1. When I fill p_a, b_p and p_c are filled too - so far so good. If I change p_b, the value of p_c should be set to that value too. - But that doesn't happen. Why?
2. Why is the code for p_b also beeing triggered for the event "on p_a". Does filling the parameter p_b trigger it?
3. If I put a "call selection-screen 1000" in the "at selection-screen on p_b" event it works. But now F8 doesn't trigger the "start-of-selection". Why?

Comment: `AT SELECTION-SCREEN` event will always be processed for both of the parameters `p_a` and `p_b` regardless whether you changed the value of this parameter or not. I don't think the sequence of execution of those blocks is guaranteed. I would rather assume that it is unexpected, so you cannot count on the fact that `ON p_a` will be executed befere `ON p_b` or the other way round. And if you do that `CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 1000` in the `AT SELECTION-SCREEN` then don't expect anything at all. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you hit Enter in a Selection-Screen, you will always go through
the "at selection-screen" events. It doesn't matter whether or not you
changed the field at all. These events are used by the
selection-screen to pass the value from the frontend to the parameter.
There is one exception: When the parameter is initial and was not
changed since the last time the event was triggered. In this case it
will not pass the value to the parameter.

(One thing to note: It doesn't matter if you define logic for the
event in your program, or in which order you write them. The
selection-screen will do this from top to bottom of the screen for
every input field. Also: These events are not triggered when you have
an obligatory parameter that isn't filled)

So the first case seems to work because of the exception. But if you
put in something for "p_b" first and than for "p_a" it doesn't
(granted you can't do that because of the obligatory parameter). "p_c" doesn't
get the value from "p_b" because it is overwriten when the "on p_c"
passes the value from the frontend.

For the third point:
When you call the selection screen there, it skips the "on p_c" event and goes to
the selection-screen you called. So the event doesn't pass the
parameter and it seems to be all good. Except not. The "at
selection-screen" event is also fired when you hit F8. So it reaches
the "call selection-screen 1000" again and goes to the screen. Also
you're just overlapping the screens. Notice how you have to hit F3
several times when you want to go back after you hit enter a bunch.

So I've given this problem a go and this is what I came up with:

```
data: gv_a type char10.
data: gv_b type char10.
data: gv_c type char10.

parameters: p_a  type c length 10.
parameters: p_b  type c length 10.
parameters: p_c  type c length 10.

initialization.
  gv_a = p_a.
  gv_b = p_b.
  gv_c = p_c.

at selection-screen on p_b.
  if p_a <> gv_a.
    p_b = p_a.
  endif.

at selection-screen on p_c.
  if p_b <> gv_b.
    p_c = p_b.
  elseif p_a <> gv_a.
    p_c = p_a.
  endif.

at selection-screen.
  gv_a = p_a.
  gv_b = p_b.
  gv_c = p_c.
```

Basically I remember the parameter values from the last time it raised
the "at selection-screen" event and check whether or not a parameter
was changed. If it was I copy it as it was defined. Also, I only
change the paramters after it was passed from the frontend. I like to
do it in the accourding "on [param]" event. That way I can change the
order on the screen without messing with the logic.

And I don't know what value is expected when both p_a and p_b were
changed. Anyways, maybe you learned a bit about selections-screens
from this.